# How to turn this JSX table into input fileds?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How would I convert this into a bunch of inputs instead of a table ?
I know the snippet is not runnable btw. If someoneone can just give me a starter or more guidance id appreciate it
like this:
[image]

```js
function MyTable(props) {
  console.log(props);
  const initState = [
    { id: 1, name: "bread", quantitiy: 50, location: "cupboard" },
    { id: 2, name: "milk", quantitiy: 20, location: "fridge" },
    { id: 3, name: "water", quantitiy: 10, location: "fridge" },
    { id: 4, name: "rice", quantitiy: 10, location: "pantry" }
  ];
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(initState);

  return (
    <table>
      <tr key={"header"}>
        {Object.keys(state[0]).map((key) => (
          <th>{key}</th>
        ))}
      </tr>
      {state.map((item) => (
        <tr key={item.id}>
          {Object.values(item).map((val) => (
            <td>{val}</td>
          ))}
        </tr>
      ))}
    </table>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyTable staff={"hello"} />, document.getElementById("target"));
```

Answer (score 1):

The `val` variable inside your `state.map` loop should be the value that you need, you can also use the reference to the `item` object above to give it a specific name for example.

Try replacing `<td>{val}</td>` with:

```
<td>
  <input type="text" value={val} name={item.name}>
</td>
```

This should help as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, this is what happens when i code without coffee

```js
<div>
      <div>
        { Object.keys(state[0]).map((key) => (
          <input type="text"   value={key} id="name" name="productName" />
        ))}
      </div>
      {state.map((item) => (
        <div key={item.id}>
          {Object.values(item).map((val) => (
            <input type="text"  value={val} id="name" name="productName" />
          ))}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
```